# When is this character relevant in Rise of Tiamat?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, npc, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen, rise-of-tiamat

In Hoard of the Dragon Queen, in [chapter 8 area 12](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/hotdq/castle-in-the-clouds#12RedWizardsRoom) in the Developments section it is stated that:

> If the characters speak to Rath Modar or his associate, Azbara Jos, they find that the Red Wizard reputation for arrogance is true (...) Rath Modar and his associate figure prominently in The Rise of Tiamat. Defeating or killing them is a serious blow to the cult’s ability to summon Tiamat.

However looking through the Rise of Tiamat adventure,

> Although Rath Modar's relevance is easy to find, I have found no mention of Azbara Jos in Rise of Tiamat at all.

Is this simply an inconsistency or did I overlook something and this character is actually relevant for Rise of Tiamat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### That character does not appear

I have searched through the book, and performed [this D&D Beyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=azbara%20jos&f=actions,compendium,conditions,skills,rules,weapon-property&c=compendium) (**potential spoilers in the D&D Beyond search**), which both revealed that the mention of the character in question is only present in *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* and not *Rise of Tiamat*.

#### You could insert him

If your players have developed a particular relationship with the character, you could insert him in a number of places, some of which I've detailed here:

> - Azbara could have played a role in helping with the summoning of the Yugaloths of the second attack, and/or participate in any of the attacks in *Episode 5: The Cult Strikes Back*
>
> - Azbara could appear in the final scene, either in the ranks of the Final Battle, or helping perform the ritual (although Azbara is not quite as powerful as the mages who perform this ritual traditionally, it wouldn't substantially impact the encounter to have a CR 4 wizard present)

Comment: Nice answer; could be worth mentioning that this is one of a number of threads that HotDQ leaves dangling and RoT fails to pick up. Some if them are explicitly called out in HotDQ as being followed up in RoT despite, yanno, not actually being followed up at all.